TextInput in react-native
 is restricted to maximum of two decimal places. When I type third decimal place, the number is added for a moment and then it dissapears. I would like the third decimal not to show up at all. How can I program do it? Thanks a lot for you help!! Patrik
<TextInput
      value={displayValue}
      onChangeText={handleInputChange}
      style={styles.input}
      keyboardType="decimal-pad"
      selection={{
        start: displayValue.length,
        end: displayValue.length,
      }}

      // Kurzorem před znakem €
 />


You can add regex here:
const handleInputChange = (text) => {
    // Use a regular expression to match the valid format (2 decimal places)
    const regex = /^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/;

    // Check if the input matches the regex
    if (regex.test(text)) {
        setDisplayValue(text);
    }
};

// Your TextInput component
<TextInput
    value={displayValue}
    onChangeText={handleInputChange}
    style={styles.input}
    keyboardType="decimal-pad"
    selection={{
        start: displayValue.length,
        end: displayValue.length,
    }}
/>

The handleInputChange function checks if the new input matches the regex. If it does, it updates the state with the new value. If it doesn’t, it simply ignores it, effectively preventing any invalid input.
I hope this will work.
